# Combine map, reduceByKey and another map

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Data is a collection of tuples in the format: (group, number)

```
data.map(a => (a._1, (a._2, 1)))
.reduceByKey((a,b) => (a._1 * b._1, a._2 + b._2))
.map(a => (a._1, pow(a._2._1, 1/a. 2._2))
```

As a total newbie in Spark - what provided code is doing? Can you explain to me this code?

Comment: The readability of the code could be greatly improved by using patter matching to unpack the tuples and using proper naming, instead of using `._1` & `._2` to access the elements of the tuples. The code  could be read somewhat as follows: For each tuple, return the same tuple but with and added one in the value _(which will be used to count)_. Then, for all values that have the same key, reduce them by multiplying their first component _(the number of your original data)_ and summing its second _(the one that was added before, thus counting how many numbers where in the same group)_...

Comment: Finally, after the reduce, your **RDD** _(as I am sure this is **Spark)_ will have just one entry for each key, the reduced value which contains the multiplication & the count of all numbers which were in the same group. Thus you map again to return the same key, but a new value that is equals to elevating the accumulated multiplication by `1 / count`. - This is how you could make it more readable: `data.mapValues(number => number -> 1L)` - `reduceByKey((a, b) => (a, b) match { case ((n1, c1), (n2, c2)) => (n1 * n2) -> (c1 + c2) })` - `mapValues { case (acc, count) => pow(acc, 1 / count)}`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez   So why do you not write an answer?

Comment: @thebluephantom being honest, I don't know. When I wrote it i was just thinking that a comment would be enough, specially because I was sure the question would be closed as OP was only asking for an explanation of the code. _(Also, I was on the cellphone, and I find writing answers there very tedious)_ - Anyways, I just hope OP had read it and found it useful.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez  well questions are too broad, not a free code writing service, but so many are in fact that, so I take your point.